# Threaded multicore platform indipendent programming in C++/QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am going to create a 3d model viewing software in c++/qt which has to be threaded, it has utilize multiple cores efficiently, and it has to be platform independent (in terms of os and cpu architecture). Can you suggest me some resources/sample codes on planning a threaded architecture, and multicore programming ?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threading books for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334568/threading-books-for-c)

Comment: @Kirill, I'd say threading for Qt is a special case since it has it's own messaging, threads, and has special needs for rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Qt has built-in support for [cross-platform multithreading](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads.html). If your application runs on 
multiple cores, [Qt will take care of distributing your threads across them](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qtconcurrent.html). If you are not happy with Qt's multithreading support, have a look at:

1. [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)
2. [Cilk Plus](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cilk-plus/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives.

Use [QtConccurent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrent.html). This package makes it possible to write multi-threaded programs without using low-level threading primitives. It has many functions such as **blockingFilter()**, **mapReduce()** etc. which make life a lot easier.

or

[QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html) and [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthreadpool.html) and [QMutex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmutex.html) and other [synchronization mechanisms](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-synchronizing.html) available in the Qt Core and do it yourself.